# How to select an entry and exit record for each user from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, union

I have the following table

```
R_ID    DATE    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
158   20161008    01      99     99
158   20161012    01      01     99
158   20161019    01      02     10
158   20161022    99      01     10
160   20161006    01      99     01
160   20161011    99      01     99
160   20161017    99      01     10
167   20161013    99      01     01
167   20161016    99      02     99
167   20161020    02      01     10
```

I want to select such that I get the following result

```
R_ID    DATE    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
158   20161008    01      01     99     -  Entry record
158   20161022    99      01     10     -  Exit Record
160   20161006    01      99     01     -  Entry record
160   20161017    99      01     10     -  Exit Record
167   20161013    99      01     01     -  Entry record
167   20161020    02      01     10     -  Exit Record

For each  R_ID:
When Col_A or Col_B = '01' and Col_C <>'10' - **It is an entry record**
When Col_C = '10' - **It is an exit record**
```

Logic here is

```
1. Select the earliest entry record 
   **and** 
2. Select the latest exit record for each R_ID
```

I'm thinking of using union like below...

```
Select * from tbl1 T
where 
T.Col_C = '10' and 
T.DATE = (select max(T2.DATE) from tbl1 T2
                                 where
                                 T2.Col_C = '10' and
                                 T3.R_ID = T.R_ID
          )

union

Select * from tbl1 K
where
(K.Col_A = '01' or K.Col_B = '01') and 
K.Col_C <> '10' and
K.DATE = (select min(K2.DATE) from tbl1 K2 where 
                      (K2.Col_A = '01' or K2.Col_B = '01') and 
                       K2.Col_C <> '10' and
                       K2.R_ID = K.R_ID   
          )
```

But using union like I did on the same table with self joins is returning me a garbage data.

Can this be achieved with joins?

Answer (score 1):

May be a simpler way... but I think this does it in a few easy to follow/maintain steps using a CTEs (common table expression)

This generates to sets of data one with the min date for each R_ID and one with the max for each R_ID then joins those sets to the base set and unions the results to get the desired results.  Since we used a union we need to wrap it all in a select to get the right order.

```
With Data(R_ID,    mDate,    Col_A,   Col_B,   Col_C) as (
    SELECT 158,   20161008,    01,      99,     99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 158,   20161012,    01,      01,     99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 158,   20161019,    01,      02,     10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 158,   20161022,    99,      01,     10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 160,   20161006,    01,      99,     01 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 160,   20161011,    99,      01,     99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 160,   20161017,    99,      01,     10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 167,   20161013,    99,      01,     01 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 167,   20161016,    99,      02,     99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 167,   20161020,    02,      01,     10 FROM DUAL),

MinRID as (SELECT R_ID, Min(mDate) MinDate from Data GROUP BY R_ID),
MaxRID as (SELECT R_ID, Max(mdate) MaxDate from Data GROUP BY R_ID),
Result as (SELECT A.R_ID, A.mDate, A.COL_A, A.COL_B, A.Col_C, 'Entry Record' as RecType
                FROM Data A
                INNER JOIN MinRID  B
                  on B.R_ID = A.R_ID
                 and B.MinDate = A.mDate

                UNION ALL

                SELECT A.R_ID, A.mDate, A.COL_A, A.COL_B, A.Col_C, 'Exit Record' as RecType
                FROM Data A
                INNER JOIN maxRID C
                  on C.R_ID = A.R_ID
                 and C.MaxDate = A.mDate)
SELECT * FROM Result ORDER BY R_ID, MDATE
```

I changed "date"'s name to mdate to avoid having to escape the column name as it's a keyword.  I also didn't include all your limiting criteria.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has a sub-query to rank all the DATE values in both directions. The sub-query is used in a UNION ALL to get the desired output.

```
with cte as (
    select R_ID
        , DATE
        , COL_A
        , COL_B
        , COL_C
        , rank() over (partition by R_ID order by DATE asc, COL_A asc ) as entry_rnk
        , rank() over (partition by R_ID order by DATE desc, COL_A asc ) as exit_rnk
    from TBL1
)
select  R_ID
        , DATE
        , COL_A
        , COL_B
        , COL_C
        , 'Entry record'
from cte
where entry_rnk = 1 
union all
select  R_ID
        , DATE
        , COL_A
        , COL_B
        , COL_C
        , 'Exit record'
from cte
where exit_rnk = 1
order by 1, 5
/
```

I'll be honest: I ignored the additional filters in the posted WHERE clauses because there was no explanation of what rules they applied. Perhaps you need to include them in the WITH clause and/or the UNION'd queries

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can get multiple rows that match the date filter and match some of the COL_A,B,C conditions but where say K.COL_C <> 10 and K2.COL_C <> 10 but K.COL_C may or may not match K2.COL_C
or T.COL_C = 10 and T2.COL_C = 10 but maybe T.COL_A and T.COL_B don't match T2.COL_A or T2.COL_B.

Here is a query that doesn't use a union.  It is similar in structure to your union query if you think about changing your 2 where clauses into an OR of the two.  It also added the COL_A, COL_B and COL_C matching.

```
Select
BASE_TABLE.*

from
     tbl1 as BASE_TABLE,

 ( select K2.R_ID, min(K2.DATE) as MINDATE, 
      K2.COL_A, K2.COL_B, K2.COL_C      
 from tbl1 K2
  where 
  (K2.Col_A = '01' or K2.Col_B = '01') and 
   K2.Col_C <> '10'
   group by K2.R_ID, K2.COL_A, K2.COL_B, K2.COL_C )
  AS ENTRY_FILTER ,

 ( select T2.R_ID, max(T2.DATE) as MAXDATE, 
        T2.COL_A,T2.COL_B, T2.COL_C       
 from tbl1 T2
                             where
                             T2.Col_C = '10'
   group by T2.R_ID, T2.COL_A,T2.COL_B, T2.COL_C
  )
  AS EXIT_FILTER

where
( ENTRY_FILTER.R_ID = BASE_TABLE.R_ID
 AND BASE_TABLE.DATE = ENTRY_FILTER.MINDATE
 and BASE_TABLE.COL_A = ENTRY_FILTER.COL_A
 and BASE_TABLE.COL_B = ENTRY_FILTER.COL_B
 and BASE_TABLE.COL_C = ENTRY_FILTER.COL_C
)
or
(
EXIT_FILTER.R_ID = BASE_TABLE.R_ID;
 AND BASE_TABLE.DATE = EXIT_FILTER.MAXDATE
 AND BASE_TABLE.COL_A = EXIT_FILTER.COL_A
 AND BASE_TABLE.COL_B = EXIT_FILTER.COL_B
 AND BASE_TABLE.COL_C = EXIT_FILTER.COL_C
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a simple MATCH_RECOGNIZE will give you an easy result:

```
   SELECT * FROM data d
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
        PARTITION BY r_id
        ORDER BY datum
        MEASURES FIRST(entry.datum) AS entry_dat, LAST(exit.datum) AS exit_dat
        PATTERN( (entry | exit | other)+ )
        DEFINE 
            entry AS (col_a = '01' OR col_b = '01') AND col_c <> '10',
            exit AS col_c = '10'
        
    )

r_id entry_dat  exit_dat
158 08/10/16    22/10/16
160 06/10/16    17/10/16
167 13/10/16    20/10/16
```

Which can easily be joined to the original data to get the result in the expected format, but that could be easier if your original data had a PK (then had 2 columns to the MEASURES to get them: FIRST(entry.pk) AND LAST(exit.pk)).